# Doctrine 2 - NativQuery with UNION

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity, union

I want hydrate a `UNION` result to an entity. My problem is, at a `UNION` I do not have alias at the result?

```
public function getDialogHistoryQuery($addr, $page = 1, $count = 10) {
    $count = (int) abs($count);
    $page = max((int) $page, 1);
    $limitStart = (int)($page - 1) * $count;
    $sql = "(SELECT 
              'in' AS direction, ib.id, ib.from_addr AS addr, ib.receive_time AS time, ib.message
            FROM 
              smsd_inbound AS ib 
            WHERE
              ib.from_addr = :addr)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT 
              'out' AS direction, ob.id, ob.to_addr, ob.log_time, ob.message
            FROM 
              smsd_outbound AS ob 
            WHERE
              ob.to_addr = :addr)
            ORDER BY time
            LIMIT :limitStart, :limitCount";
    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->getRegistry()->getEntityManager());
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('SkyDiablo\Util\SMSBundle\Entity\SMSDialog', $alias = 'ib'); //dose not work?
    $query = $this->getRegistry()->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $query->setParameter('addr', (string)$addr);
    $query->setParameter('limitStart', $limitStart);
    $query->setParameter('limitCount', $count);
    return $query;
}
```

The SQL query works fine, but in this scenario it gets no results. I have debugged it and `doctrine 2` get the right result but can't hydrate to the entity?
My "alias" is just an attempt to get anything, but there is no alias available at `UNION` ?

any tips ?

Comment: I am not familiar with doctrine, but looking at your query, I think that the second `SELECT` must put the same aliases to the columns as the first SELECT ( `... ob.to_addr AS addr, ob.log_time AS time ...` )

Comment: If you have solved the problem, Please share it.